# Is there any possible way to exempt a page or a group of pages to be counted under origin?

Tags: performance, core-web-vitals, web-vitals, website-performance

Google says: Chrome User Experience Report aggregates real-world speed data from opted-in users and requires that a URL must be public (crawlable and indexable) and have sufficient number of distinct samples that provide a representative, anonymized view of performance of the URL or origin.

Attaching the link to the article: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#why-is-the-real-user-crux-data-not-available-for-a-url-or-origin

With that said I tried modifying my robots.txt file expecting some improvements in the origin's web-vitals scores.

[Attaching screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTe9X.png)

PS: We are using WordPress

Answer (score 0):

No as per the [CrUX docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology#origin-eligibility):

> If an origin is determined to be publicly discoverable, eligible user experiences on all of that origin's pages are aggregated at the origin-level, regardless of individual page discoverability. All of these experiences count towards the origin's popularity requirement.

The only way to exclude the data at an origin-level is to host this under another domain (e.g. a sub-domain).

We get this question occasionally with admin sites (e.g. [www.example.com/admin](http://www.example.com/admin)) which sometimes don't get as much love and attention as the rest of the site and which people want to exclude (especially as they are not crawlable). However, the origin-level data is supposed to be just that - a view of all URLs in that origin by number of page views. And if those other pages are used sufficiently enough that they impact the origin-level data than that reflects the user experience of that origin.

Google Search Console groups pages differently, attempting to categorise them into different page types. So it *may* put these into a different group.

CrUX is also intended to be a high-level overview of the site in question. RUM solutions will allow you much more granularity and to slice and dice your performance data as you see fit.

Comment: Does that mean that even after adding a meta tag for de-indexing a page, the user  experience of that page is still counted in origin's score ?
Any particular RUM tool that you can suggest, it would be a great help.

Comment: As as per the quote in my answer, ALL experiences are included in the origin data. There's lots of great RUM tools out there including ones built into CDNs (Akamai, Cloudflare) if using them, or independent ones (like BlueTriangle, RUMVision, SpeedCurve). I also maintain the web-vitals.js library that allows you to collect this for free (but doesn't offer a UI to view them in).